# Berry-Esseen Type For the Unknown Variance

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Suppose we have and i.i.d. sample $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ with mean $\mu$ and finite variance.

Let $\bar{X}$ denote the sample mean and $s_n^2$ denote that sample variance.

Using classical CLT together with Slutsky's theorem it follows that
\begin{align}
\frac{\bar{X} -\mu}{ \sqrt{ s_n^2/n}} \to Z
\end{align}
where $Z$ is standard normal and the convergence is in distribution.

Question: Is there a Berry-Esseen type result?
That is let $F_n$ denote the cdf of $\frac{\bar{X} -\mu}{ \sqrt{s_n^2/n}}$, do we have something of the form:
\begin{align}
\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} | F_n(t) -\Phi(t)| \le  \frac{B}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{align}

I would guess that people have looked into this already, so a reference would be appreciated. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything myself.

Comment: There have been some papers in recent times relating to such Berry-Esseen-like inequalities in this situation. I don't have any references handy but I might be able to find one.

Comment: @Glen_b  Thanks. I would really appreciate it if you do.

Comment: Memory has kicked in. I'm pretty sure at least one of the ones I saw was on arXiv. Looking there now. No luck so far.

Comment: None of these were the papers I saw before ... which were much more recent, but it's a start: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-24/issue-1/The-Berry-Esseen-bound-for-students-statistic/10.1214/aop/1042644728.full  and https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0074828

Comment: Here's one of the ones I saw before: https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3286v2

Comment: Hopefully those papers give you enough to go on. You've got papers from decades ago and a paper (with references) from a decade ago.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks. This is very helpful.